How can I bypass screen lock on my Motorola without factory reset or wipe data?
I have a 14 year old daughter who has the same exact phone as me. She has been tlkn to someone secretly and just barely started cutting herself. I really need to find out who she's tlkn to because she wants to go outta town with them for Christmas. Can I bypass her screen lock to see who it is
